# How Zero Crossing optoisolator to work with 220VAC?

Tags: ac, opto-isolator, zero-crossing

I want to use a H11AA1 to detect Zero Crossing, but I am not sure how circuit should look like. How much voltage should LED receive inside H11AA1?

Here is datasheet:
http://www.vishay.com/docs/83608/h11aa1.pdf

By my calculation, please correct me if I am wrong.
Forward continuous current from datasheet 60mA.

```
Resistor should be 220/0.06= 3.6k
With wattage 220*0.06=13.2W
```

Here is some circuit which I found but not seem legit...

[image]

Comment: LEDs don't "receive" voltage; they *drop* voltage based on how much current is passing through them.

Comment: How much voltage can go trought leds?

Comment: Voltage doesn't go through LEDs, it drops across LEDs.

Comment: Is that led same as this:http://www.greenprophet.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/LED-lights-health-hazard.jpeg ? I know when I apply to much voltage to it, it will burn.

Comment: It will work, but it only detects 'zero' very approximately (maybe Vout high for |Vin| < 25~35V) . If you're happy with such large values for 'zero' (and thus wide pulses), it may work for you.

Comment: How can I calculate voltage drop?

Answer (score 4):

The maximum current through the LEDs has to be limited to 60mA. That would not be the normal operating current for that optoisolator.

The 230VAC RMS with 66K ohm series resistors allows a current of 230/66K = 3.4mA RMS through the LEDs. The peak current would be 4.8mA when the AC voltage reaches its very peak value.

These conditions should allow that optocoupler to work just fine.

Why do you have a doubt about the circuit now?

Comment: What wattage of resistor should be?

Comment: Each resistor will have approximately 115 volts RMS across it. At 33K the actual RMS power in each resistor would be (115 * 115)/33K = ~ 0.4W. So it seems safe to recommend 1W resistors. If you could have good cooling air flow you may be able to get 1/2W resistors to be OK.

Comment: Thanks very much, I understand now better. I will ask u some more question if I get some more problems when I try this...

Comment: I have one more question... Is possible to calculate voltage after current go trought resistors?

Comment: Are you wondering about the voltage drop across the LEDs themselves? If so that is specified as the LED Forward Voltage in the data sheet and the data sheet Figure 1.

Comment: Yes, so If I use 66K 1W resistor on 220V it will not burn LED inside opto isolator?

Comment: You would be better advised to use two 33K ohm resistors. At 1W rating each you will have plenty of margin. If you went with a single 66K resistor it would be having ~0.8W RMS of dissipation and with a 1W component rating your margin is not nearly so good.

Comment: Aha, ok. And is there any formule to calculate volate after current pass resistor? 220VAC when pass trought 33K resistor, does voltage drop?

Comment: @VladimirDjukic: You are asking very basic electronics questions. This suggests that you are not qualified to work on mains electronics and should get some experience with low-voltage circuits where the dangers can be eliminated.

Comment: It's because I am still noob in electronics. :) I need to expreriment to understand it better, thanks for your concern but I will not apply this till I don't understand it very good. Could you answer on my previous question?

Comment: @VladimirDjukic: Voltage drops when current flows.

Comment: I know that but how can I know how much will voltage drop?

Comment: I research little and I found that ohm's law is diffirent for AC power... Could you do it calculation for AC?